# FIS Editor (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I have implemented fuzzy logic using **Fuzzy Logic Toolbox** (paricularly using FIS Editor) in **MATLAB**, so it gives an output in the form of a graph. Can anyone suggest me some other way to see output in some more **meaningful** form (e.g dialog box)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of a fuzzy inference system is not a graph but is a crisp (non-fuzzy) number.

[image]

Check out the [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox User's Guide PDF](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/pdf_doc/fuzzy/fuzzy.pdf) or [the online version](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/fuzzy/) for more information (it has well-explained examples).